# mysql query join query from three tables

Tags: mysql

I have a system called "wallet system" that has a database with three tables as below:

Entities:

1. wmembers (wallet members): id, username, password, email, city etc
2. wdata: id, wid, bond, bondvalue:
3. y2014: id, fno, date, status, bond city dno

Relationships:

1. wdata.wid is foreign key for table wmembers (wmembers.id)
2. wdata.bond has a relation with y2014.fno
3. wdata.bondval has a relation with y2014.bond

I want to select all data from `wdata` for specified `wid` *and then search in y2014 if they exisit list them*

```
    $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wdata1  as a, `y2014` as b
         WHERE a.bvalue = '$pbond' and a.wid='$wid'
         and b.bond='$pbond' and a.bond = b.fno and a.bvalue = b.bond");
```

Comment: Can you please try to format/rephrase your question so that the relations are more clear?

Comment: Any time you have a table called `something_number`, alarm bells should start ringing re design.

Answer (score 0):

I am not understand your question clearly. Try something like this

```
SELECT 
m.id,username,password,email,city,
w.id,wid,w.bond,bondvalue, 
y.id,fno,date,status
FROM 
wmember m 
INNER JOIN wadat w ON m.id = w.wid 
INNER JOIN y2014 y ON m.bond = y.bond
WHERE wid = 1
```

Hoping relation between wmember and wadat is wid of wadat is id in wmember.
If the relation is not correct update the ON part in the query

> ON m.id = w.wid

To the correct relation. And if there are multiple fields need to be related use **AND** as something like this

> ON m.id = w.wid AND m.name = w.name

Refer: [mysql-using-joins](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I try to rephrase your question, and I submit an answer...

If you have all records from wdata that has at least one related record at table y2014 use this query

```
SELECT *
FROM wdata AS w
INNER JOIN  y2014 as y
    ON w.bond = y.fno
        AND w.bondval = y.bond
WHERE w.wid = $wid
```

otherwise, if you want all records of wdata with related records (if exists) of y2014 try this

```
SELECT *
FROM wdata AS w
LEFT JOIN  y2014 as y
    ON w.bond = y.fno
        AND w.bondval = y.bond
WHERE w.wid = $wid
```

Maybe my join condition is not that you want, check it please